# How to access variable from method in JDA

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I am making a Discord bot, and I'm stuck. I have 2 methods that are in the same file.

Method 1:

```
@Override
public void onSelectMenuInteraction(SelectMenuInteractionEvent event) {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(event.getValues().get(0));
}
```

Method 2:

```
@Override
public void playlistLoaded(AudioPlaylist playlist) {
    final AudioTrack Track = playlist.getTracks().get(a);
}
```

Question: How can I access variable a from method 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set it as a field

```java
public class SomeClass extends ListenerAdapter {
     private int track;
     @Override
     public void onSelectMenuInteraction(SelectMenuInteractionEvent event) {
          track = Integer.parseInt(event.getValues().get(0));
     }
     @Override
     public void playlistLoaded(AudioPlaylist playlist) {
          final AudioTrack Track = playlist.getTracks().get(track);
     }
```

Or using a stack

```java
public class SomeClass extends ListenerAdapter {
     private final Stack<Integer> tracks = new Stack<Integer>();
     @Override
     public void onSelectMenuInteraction(SelectMenuInteractionEvent event) {
          int track = Integer.parseInt(event.getValues().get(0));
          tracks.push(track);
     }
     @Override
     public void playlistLoaded(AudioPlaylist playlist) {
          final AudioTrack Track = playlist.getTracks().get(tracks.pop());
     }
```